# Prestashop 1.6.0.9 - $product->save() in loop takes only 10 products

Tags: php, xml, import, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm having problems when trying to come out with some xml import for my shop via object `$product`. When I try to fill in `$product` members, everything works fine, it loops all over cca. 800 products I have in my xml. But when I add method save in the end of loop, it takes only first 10 products and never do more.

I tried to put `sleep(1)` after `$product->save()` as I thought that SQL drops connection because of large income queries, but it didn't help neither.

Do you guys know why is this happening? Below is my code (I'm not pasting xml file here as I think it is not important).

Working with Prestashop 1.6.0.9.

```
<?            
include('../config/config.inc.php');
include('../init.php');    

if (file_exists('exportgoods.xml')) 
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('exportgoods.xml');


    foreach ($xml->PRODUCTS->PRODUCT as $jmena_produktu)
    {
        if($jmena_produktu->PRODUCER == "2"):           
        $reference=$string = str_replace(' ', '', $jmena_produktu->NAME);    
        $id_product = (int)Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT id_product FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product WHERE reference = \''.pSQL($reference).'\'');
        $product = $id_product ? new Product((int)$id_product, true) : new Product();
        $product->reference = $reference;
        $product->price = (float)$jmena_produktu->PRICEWITHDPH;
        $product->id_category_default = 2;
        $product->category = 15;
        $product->name[1] = (string)$jmena_produktu->NAME;
        $product->description[1] = (string)$jmena_produktu->LONGDESCRIPTION;
        $product->description_short[1] = (string)$jmena_produktu->DESCRIPTION;
        $product->link_rewrite[1] = Tools::link_rewrite($reference);
        if (!isset($product->date_add) || empty($product->date_add))
            $product->date_add = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $product->date_upd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $id_product ? $product->updateCategories(array(2,15)) : $product->addToCategories(array(2,15));
        #Here start my problem
        $product->save();
        echo 'Product <b>'.$product->name[1].'</b> '.($id_product ? 'updated' : 'created').'<br />';
        endif;
    }
} 
else 
{
    exit('Failed to open exportgoods.xml.');
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar problem and I was using `simplexml_load_file()` too. I'm not sure if that was the problem back then, but here goes nothing:

```
$data = file_get_contents('exportgoods.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
```

Sometimes XML elements are nested inside each other differently from what you see while doing a `var_dump($xml)` or `print_r($xml)` on it. *XML is a strange beast if you ask me.*

And what do you see when you *only* print out `$jmena_produktu->NAME`, just to check if it goes further then 10. Something like this:

```
foreach ($xml->PRODUCTS->PRODUCT as $jmena_produktu)
{
    echo $jmena_produktu->NAME . '</br>';    
}
exit;
```

Note the `exit`, so it doesn't execute the other code.